# JSON fetched from URL differs

Tags: java, json

I have a test class which has 4-5 tests in which one of the test fetches JSON from given URL. When that one particular test is run the output looks like below

```
{"result":[{"result":[...]}]}
```

But when I run all the tests in the test class the same test mentioned above returns the below JSON

```
{"result":[]}
```

How do I fix it?

When the same URL is run in browser the JSON obtained is

```
{"result":[]}
```

JUNIT test is as below

```
@Test    
public void test(){    
    PostcodeLookup.reverseGeocoding(0.629834723775309,51.7923246977375).limit(100).radius(2000).wideSearch(true).asjson();
}
```

The below URL is the one which is generated

```
https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes?lon=0.629834723775309&lat=51.7923246977375&limit=100&radius=2000&widesearch=true
```

PostcodeLookup.java

```
public class PostcodeLookup {

public static PostcodeLookup reverseGeocoding(Double longitude, Double latitude) {
    PostcodeLookup.longitude=longitude;
    PostcodeLookup.latitude=latitude;
}

public static PostcodeLookup limit(int limit) {
    PostcodeLookup.limit=limit;
}

public static PostcodeLookup radius(int radius) {
    PostcodeLookup.radius=radius;
}

public static PostcodeLookup widesearch(boolean widesearch) {
    PostcodeLookup.widesearch=widesearch;
}

public JSONObject asjson() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    String url = "";
    url = url.concat("lon=").concat(String.valueOf(longitude));
    url = url.concat("&lat=").concat(String.valueOf(latitude));
    if (getLimit() != 0) {
        url = url.concat("&limit=").concat(String.valueOf(limit));
    }
    if (getRadius() != 0) {
        url = url.concat("&radius=").concat(String.valueOf(radius));
    }
    if (isWideSearch()) {
        url = url.concat("&widesearch=").concat(String.valueOf(wideSearch));
    }
    return JsonFetcher.urlToJson(new URL(LOOKUP_URL.concat(url)));
}
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing what your code is doing or how you ran the tests

Comment: Could you provide the code of your tests, pls?

Comment: What's `PostcodeLookup`?

Comment: `PostcodeLookup` is a class which accumulates the values for query for URL

Comment: Can you attach source of `PostcodeLookup` as well?

Comment: Please attach the actual source of this class. The fragments you've attached do not even compile.

Comment: @Banthar All the code is [here](https://github.com/spdeepak/postcodes-io-java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/postcode/io/initializers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by field:

```
com.postcode.io.initializers.ReverseGeocoding.json
```

It's initialized by previous test but never cleared. Value leaks to next test changing the behavior of tested method.

You should avoid passing values via static fields. It might seem convenient or more readable but in reality it makes your code hard to follow and prone to bugs.

Instead of:

```
PostcodeLookup.reverseGeocoding(0.629834723775309, 51.7923246977375).limit(100).radius(2000).wideSearch(true).asjson()
```

Just do:

```
PostcodeLookup.reverseGeocoding(0.629834723775309, 51.7923246977375, 100, 2000, true);
```

Pass all parameters via method arguments. Make sure not to modify any static state.